# update canvas lineJoin and lineCap properties with javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html-select

How can I get lineJoin and lineCap updated when selecting an option from the list?

https://jsfiddle.net/7cao1r1b/

```
<select name="line" id="line" onchange="handleUpdate()">
  <option value="round" checked>round</option>
  <option value="miter">miter</option>
</select>
```

in js:

```
function handleUpdate() {
  const option = document.querySelector('select').value;
  ctx.strokeStyle = this.value;
  ctx.lineWidth = this.value;
  ctx.lineJoin = option;
  ctx.lineCap = option;
  console.log(option);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The option ctx.lineJoin only applies to paths that have joins.

eg

```
   ctx.beginPath(); // begins a new path. there is no join from the previous path possible
   ctx.moveTo(100,100);
   ctx.lineTo(100,200;
   // adding a move to means that the lines above is not joined to the one below
   ctx.moveTo(100,200);
   ctx.lineTo(200,200);
   ctx.stroke();
```

To use the linejoin option you need to join the path segments by not using moveTo or beginPath between line segments and use close path to join a line back to the previous moveTo

```
   ctx.beginPath(); 
   ctx.moveTo(100,100);
   ctx.lineTo(100,200; 
   ctx.lineTo(200,200); // a join 
   ctx.stroke();
```

In your snippet you are correctly using the lineCap

Comment: So, in fact, I don't need the lineJoin.